# Kenlm language model scoring with Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, nlp, n-gram, kenlm

I'm mid-way through a Java project using a '.arpa' file to extract n-gram probabilities.
Ideally I would like to use a '.klm' file (created using the '.arpa' file), similar to:

```
model = kenlm.LanguageModel('languageModel.klm')
model.score('The dog chased the ball.')
```

however kenlm for Java isn't supported on windows.
Does anyone know of any alternatives to score sentences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by just using a virtual machine to run the project using kenlm